# Customize slot values of amazon alexa skill intent per session or user

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing amazon alexa skill and I would like to customize values of Custom Slot Type for each user of my skill. I can't fill the list of values of my slot with all possible values because it will be too big and the quality of speach recognition will be very low. How can I specify the list of possible values for slot on per user/session basis?

Comment: I've been interested in this too, and it seems so far like you can't - the slot values seem to be necessarily global/static, which has been very limiting for me. If anyone provides an answer which shows otherwise, I'll be very excited.

Comment: @sphanley, thanks for opinion. I think that it impossible too. Maybe you can advice any speech recognition tool/service, that allow to customize "grammar" ("intent") for each end-user/session. As I know it is possible only with local solutions such as Windows SAPI (Speech API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you can't.  Although it does seem like some built in skills have the ability to do this such as music, so it would seem that it is technically possible using the platform, just not available to third party developers yet.